# Reference request for Bayesian problem formulation

Tags: bayesian, references

In Bayesian inference, there are two parts: the problem formulation, where the structure of the problem with parameters is built, and the solution of Bayesian inference, through MCMC, grid or normal approximation, etc.  Most references I see spend the vast majority of their time on the solution space in Bayesian inference.  Is there a good book that focuses on the first part of the problem?  McElreath's Statistical Rethinking and Gelman et al. Bayesian Data Analysis do this a bit, but McElreath's examples are generally more simple than what I'm looking for, and Gelman doesn't have enough examples.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what are you asking for. Are you looking for a methodology textbook?

Comment: @utobi, I'm looking for a reference on problem formulation, that focuses less on the mechanics of solving, and more on the architecting of the solution framework.  I will give some examples in the question text.